# Android expression expected JsonObject

Tags: android, json, android-intent

Hi everyone I'm trying to pass a json object to a second activity to display other informations, but getting an error "expression expected".

My class :

```
public class Pokemon implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private Integer attack;
    private Integer defense;
    private Integer evolveLevel;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public Integer getattack() { return attack; }

    public Integer getdefense() { return defense; }

    public Integer getEvolveLevel() { return evolveLevel; }

    protected Pokemon(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        type = in.readString();
        attack = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : in.readInt();
        defense = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : in.readInt();
        evolveLevel = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(type);
        if (attack == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
            dest.writeInt(attack);
        }
        if (defense == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
            dest.writeInt(defense);
        }
        if (evolveLevel == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
            dest.writeInt(evolveLevel);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Pokemon> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Pokemon>() {
        @Override
        public Pokemon createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Pokemon(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Pokemon[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Pokemon[size];
        }
    };
}
```

intent :

```
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
           intent.putExtra("Pokemon", Pokemon);
            view.getContext().startActivity(pokemon);
        }
    });
```

I get an error on this line :  intent.putExtra("Pokemon", Pokemon);
It underlines Pokemon and says "expression expected"

I can't launch my project, and I don't understand that error, anyone have any ideas ?

[EDIT] 
Full dataAdapter:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private ArrayList<Pokemon> mArrayList;
private ArrayList<Pokemon> mFilteredList;



public DataAdapter(ArrayList<Pokemon> arrayList) {
    mArrayList = arrayList;
    mFilteredList = arrayList;

}

@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    viewHolder.tv_name.setText(mFilteredList.get(i).getName());
    viewHolder.tv_version.setText(mFilteredList.get(i).getName());
    viewHolder.tv_api_level.setText(mFilteredList.get(i).getType());

    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Pokemon", mFilteredList.get(i));
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Pokemon_List", mFilteredList);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return mFilteredList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

            String charString = charSequence.toString();

            if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                mFilteredList = mArrayList;
            } else {

                ArrayList<Pokemon> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Pokemon marraylist : mArrayList) {

                    if (marraylist.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString) ||  marraylist.getType().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                        filteredList.add(marraylist);
                    }
                }

                mFilteredList = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            mFilteredList = (ArrayList<Pokemon>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView tv_name,tv_version,tv_api_level;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        tv_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_version = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_version);
        tv_api_level = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_api_level);

    }
}
```

}

[EDIT2]

my Main2Activity : 
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView attack;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Pokemon pokemon = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Pokemon");
    attack.setText(pokemon.getattack().toString());



}
```

}

Display of name and type in my first activity :

[List of Pokemons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZVIU.png)

Stack Trace :

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: fr.clementineferreol.myteamrocket, PID: 3137
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.clementineferreol.myteamrocket/fr.clementineferreol.myteamrocket.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at fr.clementineferreol.myteamrocket.Main2Activity$override.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:17)
                      at fr.clementineferreol.myteamrocket.Main2Activity$override.access$dispatch(Main2Activity.java)
                      at fr.clementineferreol.myteamrocket.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:0)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: If you are getting another error after making the changes from the answers here, you should post a new question rather than edit this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `startActivity` by intent and add object to extra. but you are passing pokemon object to `startActivity` and adding Pokemon class to extra. Change that it will work fine.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("Pokemon", pokemon);
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Edited :

You can remove the onclickListener from ViewHolder and You can add it bindView like this, and you are sending Parcelable list it should be send through putParcelableArrayListExtra and putExtra, and if you want to send single element you can get from the list and you can send.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    viewHolder.tv_name.setText(mFilteredList.get(i).getName());
    viewHolder.tv_version.setText(mFilteredList.get(i).getName());
    viewHolder.tv_api_level.setText(mFilteredList.get(i).getType());

    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Pokemon", mFilteredList.get(i));
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Pokemon_List", mFilteredList);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thx for you answer ! I replaced and now get that error : cannot resolve symbol "pokemon"

Comment: could you please and your variable name which you declared in that method or class for Pokemon

Comment: And you variable ? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: You should give the variable name which you want to send in put Extra, I gave as pokemon, **intent.putExtra("Pokemon", pokemon);**, i am asking what is the variable name you gave for Pokemon

Comment: intent.putExtra("Pokemon", Pokemon); you added this right.?  Pokemon is the variable name you declared in your class..?

Comment: I replaced my code with yours, when I launch my app and click on one of the item of my recycler view my app crashes and I'm getting that error : 

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String fr.clementineferreol.myteamrocket.Pokemon.getName()' on a null object reference


I updated my code so you can see what I've wrote to get the intent in my main2activity

Comment: could you please update your latest adapter..? i can check that only how you are sending the data in intent.

Comment: You are sending in intent like this  **intent.putExtra("Pokemon", mFilteredList.get(i));**  and you are getting in Main2Actiivty like this **Pokemon pokemon = bundle.getParcelable("attack");** see the keys its different, it should be same.

Comment: I tried to put the same in both and it's still sending the same error :/ saying my Object is null

Comment: Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Pokemon pokemon = bundle.getParcelable("attack");
            attack.setText(pokemon.getName());
        }  remove this and add **Pokemon pokemon = getIntent().getParcelableExtra([your key]);** because you sent in intent and setting in Bundle and send the data.

Comment: I updated my post so you can see what I have in my two mainActivities in every updates, but I still get the same error

Comment: first, try to check pokemon.getName() you are getting the value or not because in your adapter you are using that only.

Comment: Yes I get name and type, those are display in my first activity in a recyclerView, but when i click on one of the items it crashes and give that error

Comment: Please try to get the name and type instead of getattack() in Main2Activity for checking.

Comment: OK sorry , I did try getName() instead of getAttack() and the same behaviour happened

Comment: can you add a stack trace now..?

Comment: How do I do that  ?

Comment: add your crash log from logcat.

Comment: sorry problem is your TextView you didn't initialize the TextView, So remove that and try to print using log and check

Comment: I printed getName() and getattack() and I get the right name and right attack number ! Why can't I get it in the TextView ? because it exists in my xml

Comment: Great!!, Please initialize your TextView and show in that.

Comment: By initialize you mean get it by calling its id ?

Answer (score 1):

startActivity needs intent as input and not pokemon instance. pokemon is the object instance that would like to pass in the second activity which can be retrieved thru the intent.

You can either construct pokemon either in the onclick method or construct pokemon outside onClick method and have it available by declaring it in the MainActivity class.

OPTION1: construct pokemon inside onclick

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // construct pokemon here
        Pokemon pokemon = null;
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Pokemon", pokemon);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

OPTION2: construct pokemon outside onclick

```
Pokemon pokemon = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // construct pokemon here

    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Pokemon", pokemon);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand now !!

Comment: He is using this in adapter class, not Activity, We should not add a global variable for a single item in Adapter class, See my answer.

Comment: @Rémy - you accepted answer today early morning and then unaccepted answer few hours back?

Comment: Sorry, I had others errors resolved with the other answer

Comment: np, if it resolved your issues which allowed you to proceed and discover new errors then at least vote my answer up so it shows it did resolve ur first level of issues. :)

Comment: There is a up and down button around 0 near my answer, to vote up press up button and to vote down press down button, once you vote up 0 will be 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the class name Pokemon with Capital P, i guess you want to pass pokemon with a lowercase p. Which is causing the error you are not passing the object of that class.

Hope this helps.